# Convert a code from Oracle Forms 6i to 10g

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I wrote a java program which calling from my oracle form. I mean there is a button on my oracle form when I press it this program will running (java program)

previous time I used oracle form 6i so there wasn't any issue. I want to run my program on 10g now. I think this code need to change.

would you help me how I can convert below code work in 10g please?

```
 lv_path := 'java -client -classpath
 SMT\ojdbc14.jar;SMT\lipstikLF-1.1.jar;SMT\swing-layout.jar;SMT\smt.jar
 Main.GUI.SmRun '||USER||' '||lv_role;


 HOST(lv_path, NO_SCREEN);
```

I think I need to change host but I am not sure to what... and also that syntax I wrote is working in 10g as well?

Comment: Was your 6i form web-delivered or client/server?

Comment: it is Client/server...we use it as application not web base.

Answer (score 3):

> **APC -** Was your 6i form web-delivered or client/server?
>   **Rima -** it is Client/server...we use it as application not web base

You have missed a crucial aspect of Forms 10g: it is web-delivered only.  As was 9i (although not many people used that version).

This means that you will have to re-write any part of your Forms application which relies on client-side interaction.

`Host` is a classic example.  That doesn't work any more; if it did work it would run on the application server, and that is not behaviour you would want in a multi-user environment.    You will need to re-write your form to use the `CLIENT_HOST` command in the WebUtil  library.  WebUtil is a collection of functions Oracle provided to implement client-server behaviours in the new web-delivered architecture.  [Find out more](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/webutil-090641.html).

You should also read the [Forms Upgrade Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/forms-upgrade-reference-128184.pdf).